# Run specific file always vscode-code-runner

Tags: vscode-code-runner

Is there any setting for vscode-code-runner to setup a file that would be always run when I click on run button regardless which file is open in editor currently.

Answer (score 1):

as of writing this comment i do not believe it's possible with this extension. The next best thing i can recommend is to execute the file you want to run with coderunner, then copy the command that it generated and executed. You can then paste this command in your `setting.json` file as a custom command like so

```json
{
    "code-runner.customCommand": "<created command>",
}
```

To execute the custom command from anywhere in your workspace, do `ctrl+alt+K`

You can also create a `launch.settings` file to [run and debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) your code from the debug tab which you can then execute with `ctrl+shift+D`

it's not as slick as a nice run button but it's better than nothing